# Create arrays with subarrays in laravel based on database record

Tags: php, database, laravel

I want to display something like this: (which sort the dates from the original array into new arrays)

1. 01.01.2021: 5
2. 02.01.2021: 3

and so on... I already got the info stored in an array, and sorted by date. I just cannot figure out how to add a similar date-row to an array within that array automatically. not only that, but I want to echo it at the same time.
I'm absolutely stuck on this. Please help. By the way, the record->date is a format like this: 01.01.2021 15:00

```
@php
    $records = DB::table('bookings')->get();
    $records = $records->sortBy('date')->toArray();
    $array = array();
@endphp
@foreach($records as $record)
    somehting in here
@endforeach
```

After some answers, I now have this: But it still does not work. Error: "Undefined array key "2021-07-30 15:00""

```
<?php
    $records = DB::table('bookings')->get()->sortBy('date')->toArray();
    $array = array();
    foreach($records as $record){
        if(array_key_exists($array[$record->date], $array)) {
            $array[$record->date] = $array[$record->date] +1;
        }else{
            $array[$record->date] = 1;
        }
    }
    foreach($array as $value_key => $value_value){
        echo $value_key . " : " . $value_value;
    }
    ?>
```

After some quick debugging, I think the problem with this code is that it checks for an array which is not there, and it fails. But when I make the array in the else statement (with commenting out stuff) then it works. So I have still no idea how o implement the statement to check if it exists or not.

Comment: What's your question about this? This looks like something you should **not** do in a template, but in your controller

Comment: I want to sort the dates in the list $records by sorting them into arrays, where the date is the same. For example:
01.01.2021: 5
02.01.2021: 7
And so on

Comment: Please add **all clarification** to your question **by editing it**, not to the comment section

Comment: Once more: what have you tried to resolve the problem? Why not put this into your controller, or any other service, such that you could write a test covering the proper functionality of that sorting algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 @php
$records = App\Booking::pluck('date')->toArray();
foreach ($records as $record){
count[] = App\Booking::where('date' , $record)->pluck('date')->count();
}
dd(array_unique($records) , count);
@endphp
```

if input is

```
01.01.2021
01.01.2021
01.01.2021
01.02.2021
01.02.2021
01.03.2021
01.04.2021
```

then output will be

```
01.01.2021 , 3
01.02.2021 , 2
01.03.2021 , 1
01.04.2021 , 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, the code does not work for me. "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection::pluck()"

Comment: it is because @php and endphp is not called i have updated

Comment: are you using it in blade?

Comment: Yes. The file is called admin.blade.php

Comment: It's printing out 3 things, but I want it to sort it as mentioned above

Comment: Ok show me your output according to my code and then show me your desired output

Comment: The output I got is simple. 3 rows with this: 01.01.2021 15:00. That three times, because I got three records

Comment: Do you want unique date i mean if date is repeated it should print that once?

Comment: Each date should be printed once, with a length count 2021: 5

Comment: Ok i got it now i understand i will update the code later after few minutes

Comment: Thanks, I added something more to the top. Check it out, and see what we can do about that

Answer (score 0):

```
@php

$records = DB::table('bookings')->get();
$records = $records->sortBy('date')->toArray();
$array = array();
@endphp
@foreach($records as $record)
    if (array_key_exists($array[$record->date],$array))
    {
        $array[$record->date] = $array[$record->date] + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        $array[$record->date] = 1;
    }
@endforeach

@foreach ($array as $value_key => $value_value) 
    {{$value_key}} {{$value_value}} 
@endforeach
```

Comment: @ImCoding Please try with above custom solution.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Also, please explain why you solve this in a template (which should mostly cover outputting the data) instead of a controller

Comment: @VishalPGothi thanks for your answer, however, I cannot get it to work

Answer (score 0):

I found the working code, thanks to some google searches and some good answers. If anyone wants it, here it is:

```
<?php
    $records = DB::table('bookings')->get()->sortBy('date')->toArray();
    $array = array();
    foreach($records as $record){
        if(isset($array[$record->date]) ? $array[$record->date] : null) {
            $array[$record->date] = $array[$record->date] +1;
        }else{
            $array[$record->date] = 1;
        }
    }
    ?>
    @foreach($array as $value_key => $value_value)
        {{$value_key . " : " . $value_value}}
        <br>
    @endforeach
```

And the output will be something like 01.05.2021 15:00: 3